# GitHub - HTTPS access

Tags: git, https, github

I am unable to clone my repository via HTTPS:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/walterjwhite/project.configuration.git
Initialized empty Git repository in ./project.configuration/.git/
error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Connection refused while accessing https://github.com/walterjwhite/project.configuration.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I have configured .netrc with my login and password as well as the machine or server I am connecting to.

Comment: The same scenario I am facing for bitbucket. Any solutions are appreciated...

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As you did saw yourself in [GitHub support](http://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support#comment-8469), [Scott Schacon](http://github.com/schacon) himself suggested:

> So I guess your `.netrc` is incorrect or something?
>   Try removing the info from your `.netrc` and cloning first (since it's a public repo).

If it isn't a GitHub server issue, it could be your firewall.
And/or your proxy (`git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxy:xxx`).

Comment: Ah, you're right, I forgot that I needed to configure my proxy.

Comment: I still have the problem where it prompts me for my password and enter does not submit my password, it just sits there.

git clone https://walterjwhite@github.com/walterjwhite/project.configuration.git

Comment: @Walter: did you set your [github token](http://help.github.com/git-email-settings/)? Did you [add the ssh public key to your GitHub account](http://help.github.com/msysgit-key-setup/)? And did you try an https GitHub address? `git clone https://walterjwhite@github.com/walterjwhite/project.configuration.git`

Comment: Yes, I can work on my github stuff from home just fine.  When I go to select coffee shops and work there, I cannot use the SSH method, so I have to use the Smart HTTP proxy.  When I copied and pasted the address, stackoverflow took off the https part, but yes, that is what I tried.  That is where it hangs, when it prompts me for my password.  CTRL+C gets me out.

Comment: To remove the global proxy variable `git config --global --unset http.proxy`. Don't forget the `--global`. Note that this doesn't solve the 403 error, it solve the `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/whatever/': Failed connect to github.com:<yourproxyport>; No error`. *(This error message is buggy indeed:  you're connecting to github.com:443, not on your proxy port)*.

Answer (score 11):

Just to add to this discussion, for some reason or another, it seems to work for me when I use http rather than https.

Comment: On my server I know that this was because I didn't have the proper root certificates for GitHub installed. Once we got these installed https worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add you might also check if GitHub's system is healthy at [GitHub System Status](https://status.github.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility that worked without trouble for me was to use the SSH option for clone.

`git clone git@github.com:walterjwhite/project.configuration.git`

You have to upload an SSH key to Github to use this, but it got me around the https problem.