# Is an SSH Key Required to clone a public github account?

Tags: github, repository, ssh-keys

Does github require all cloning, of both public and private repositories, to use an SSH public key? Maybe a better question, is can git clone a github repo without a ssh key at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can use https protocol, as mentioned in "[GitHub - Https access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512202/github-https-access/3514762#3514762)".
You would then use your GitHub login/password in a `~/.netrc` file (which can be a [security concern](http://_netrc/.netrc%20alternative%20to%20cURL)).
Note: [on Windows, that would be an _netrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows/6031266#6031266).

Since GitHub supports [smart http protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702731/git-fails-when-pushing-commit-to-github/2704113#2704113)  (as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78991/why-is-github-more-popular-than-gitorious/3207867#3207867)), you can use that for cloning/pulling *and* for pushing.

[image: smart http]

Answer (score 0):

SSH Key is used for more safety communication. Is not necessary, although using SSH Key is usefull because encrypte communication and also does not involve password.

Answer (score -3):

No.  A SSH key is only needed to push to a public repo on github, not to pull from one (although the easiest method to get a clone you can later push to uses the same key to pull as to push, that isn't the only way to work).

Comment: SSH is not necessary if you use the HTTPS URL.