# getting 443 error while checking out code from github

Tags: github, openstack-nova

I am trying to get the nova code from github and I got the following error :

```
#git clone https://github.com/openstack/nova.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/avikki/Desktop/nt/nova/.git/
error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Operation now in progress while accessing https://github.com/openstack/nova.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

can you suggest what to do ?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me without errors. You may be experiencing connectivity issues - notice that the error description says that git `Failed to connect to github.com:443`. Check out this answer: [GitHub - HTTPS access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512202/github-https-access) which offers some possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem twice. I'm running Linux. The first time, I was on a network that required a proxy. 
See this link for how to fix proxy settings: [How do I pull from a Git repository through an HTTP proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy)

Then I took my proxy-configured computer to a network that did not require a proxy and got this error again.

To un-configure my computer for a proxy,

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
unset ftp_proxy
unset all_proxy
unset FTP_PROXY
unset ALL_PROXY
unset HTTPS_PROXY
unset HTTP_PROXY
```

I'm not sure I needed to unset all of those variables, but I certainly needed more than just the first two.