# Git clone not working - error 443

Tags: git, github

I am working from home and am trying to clone a repo from Github and am getting the following error:

```
git clone https://github.com/account/repo.git
```

Also tried

```
git clone git://github.com/account/repo.git

Error: Failed connect to github.com:443; No error while accessing https://github.com/account/repo/info/refs?service=git-upload-pac
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I even tried to use SSH and this is what I get:

> ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number fatal: could
>   not read from remote repository.

I was just able to clone it on my laptop so I know that I have the correct permissions, I just need help trying to figure out why this is happening on my desktop and it seems that all of the other suggestions don't seem to be working.

- I am not using a proxy.
- I cannot do pulls on other repos that already exist either.

**EDIT**
Ok I ran the command suggested, here are the results:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -vvv git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [204.232.175.90] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 204.232.175.90 port 22: Not owner
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What was the command line that you used?

Comment: The actual command or what client? The client I was the git bash for windows, and then I installed just the vanilla git - neither worked. Same command client on laptop worked.

Comment: I added the git commands.

Comment: 443 is not an error number, it's the port number for the https protocol.

Comment: Please post the output of following: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -vvv git@github.com`. Replace `id_rsa` with a valid github key if needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git SSH error: "Connect to host: Bad file number"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number)

Comment: What happens if you try `git clone git@github.com/account/repo.git` ?

Comment: It comes back with an error of: fatal: repository does not exist. Although I know it does. Again I can deal with github fine on my laptop and at work. Do you think this means something?

Comment: Have you checked your proxy sestings?

Comment: I'm not on a proxy - that I'm aware of at least. Any help on where to check this would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GitHub - HTTPS access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512202/github-https-access)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this may be general but I decided I wanted to get this answered, so here is what I did and it is now working correctly:

- Uninstalled ALL git clients through windows (I had a couple initially for testing)
- Installed the basic git bash from [git](http://git-scm.com/)
- Turned off smart screen and ensured firewall and defender were off (they were)

Tried it again and it now works. My best guess is there was a mis-configuration somewhere - probably a wrong key (not sure how that happened since I updated it). At any rate it is working. It's probably the nuclear option but I hope this helps someone else that runs into this.

Comment: Were firewall and denfender turned off when you originally encountered the problem >? It seems as if port 443 and port 22 were both blocked. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number

Comment: No, I wish though, it's the weirdest thing. even when checking with netstat the ports are not being used, no matter what I did. It's just a very finicky type of problem. I actually just had it happen again, changed nothing and restarted and it ended up working again. I'm thinking I may need to do a good cleaning.

Comment: when in doubt, throw it out... and restart from a fresh system/install.

Comment: Too technical! Is there another alternative way to resolve this? Your answer might not be effective for everyone. Too long process when uninstalling.

Answer (score 3):

I could resolve the 443 error by issuing this command :

```
git config --global http.proxy <proxyname:port>
```

Comment: Please explain the idea behind this and why it may have helped so that people can fully understand your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this means that your network is protected by a proxy server. To config git to use proxy, use this command:

```
git config --global http.proxy <http[s]://userName:password@proxyaddress:port>
```

if the proxy server doesn't have username and passeord, use this command

```
git config --global http.proxy <proxyaddress:port>
```

Comment: git config --global http.proxy <http[s]://userName:password@proxyaddress:port> Works like a charm to me

Comment: how do you find the proxy address. Is the username your github username?