# Error 443 : Installing Phabricator on Debian 6 Server?

Tags: git, debian, vps, phabricator

I tried to install phabricator on the debian server, and has conducted several commands to my server:

```
# sudo apt-get install mysql-server apache2 git-core git php5 php5-mysql php5-gd php5-curl php-apc php5-cli -y
# mkdir /var/www/phabricator && cd $_
```

and, when I try to run the command:

```
# git clone https://github.com/phacility/libphutil.git
```

an error message:

```
Cloning into libphutil...
error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Operation now in progress while accessing https://github.com/phacility/libphutil.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

My question is:
how to solve this problem, if there are any installation steps are missed?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

As [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89510/7490), check the output of `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone ...`

If you have a proxy configured for internet access, [you will have to set it up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512202/6309) on your Debian session as well (`export http_proxy=http://...` and `export https_proxy=http://...` )

Comment: I had the same issue when I hadn't yet setup my necessary proxy